# Error in AIX : 0516-040 : Unable to read the specified physical volume

Tags: ibm, aix, electrical-power

Please provide me your valuable suggestions on the error beow in AIX. When I'm running the following command on the AIX server `lsvg -l rootvg` I'm getting this error:

```
0516-040 : Unable to read the specified physical volume 
descriptor area.
```

Comment: 1. Are there any fail disk errors in the error logs?
2. What type of disk is this? physical storage, SAN, etc.?

Comment: Hi Alvin, No Failed disk in the server side , no Disk error logs found on the errpt , this disk coming from EMC san , we have upgraded EMC powerpath after the we are facing this error  ,

Comment: I am not familiar with EMC powerpath. Just to double confirm, are your update steps correct? I googled and found this http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/interesting-aix/powerpath-upgrade-51151